# linq XML Sum IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In the following query:

```
var foundNode3 = (from e in root.Descendants(df + "Inv")
            where e.Descendants(df + "Document").Any(item =>(string)item.Element(df + "InvS").Value == "N")
            select e.Element(df + "DocT").Element(df + "EndT").Value);
```

Output: 23.98, 12.34, 24.4...

Now to make the Sum()

```
var foundNode3 = (from e in root.Descendants(df + "Inv")
            where e.Descendants(df + "Document").Any(item =>(string)item.Element(df + "InvS").Value == "N")
            select double.Parse(e.Element(df + "DocT").Element(df + "EndT").Value)).Sum();
```

FormatException: malformed string on input

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: So what do you want to do?  Only sum up the strings that are valid doubles and skip the invalid strings?  If you can show us some strings that aren't properly parsed and know what they *should* be parsed to, then perhaps we could help you write a working parse function, or what?   What is it that your program *should* do?

Comment: Can you show all values from first query (including empty values)?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the input to double.Parse isn't parseable.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx
Double.Parse(string s) throws FormatException on invalid input s.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do write it with from, but changing it like the following may help:

```
var foundNode3 = root.Descendants(df + "Inv")
    .Where(e => e.Descendants(df + "Document")
                 .Any(item =>(string)item.Element(df + "InvS").Value == "N"))
    .Select(e =>
    {
        double value;
        string sValue = e.Element(df + "DocT").Element(df + "EndT").Value;
        if(double.TryParse(sValue, out value))
            return value;
        return 0;
    })
    .Sum();
```